# Unable to customise UITableViewCell for specific Device

Tags: swift, uitableview, constraints

[image]

I am using devicekit meaning that if the phone detects its type (5s,6 etc...) then it will load a specific set of constraints that I have outlined. So I designed the constraints for my table view cell for the Xs but while using DeviceKit and setting them for the 5s, it doesn't update them. Here is the code. This function is loaded in the view did load.

```
func deviceKitConstraints() {
    if device.isOneOf(smallGroup) {
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell
            cell.regoAnswer.center = CGPoint(x: self.view.center.x, y: self.view.center.y)
            return cell
        }
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

It goes off the screen which it shouldn't if the updates/constraints for this device would work.

Comment: Unless this is a very special use case (optimization / additional logic not outlined in your question), maybe you should take a look at Size Classes (https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/designing-for-size-classes-in-ios/). They will help you achieve the same thing without writing code and in the process help you separate your logic from your design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method is inside another method and this makes it invisible if this should be a delegate method.

Put it in the global scope of your view controller and set it cell depending on conditions inside of the method (if it is `UITableViewController`, put `override` keyword before this method)

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    ...

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if device.isOneOf(smallGroup) {
            ... // small
        } else {
            ... // large
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Within your ViewController or where the tableView is stated:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if device.isOneOf(smallGroup) {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! SmallCustomCell

            return cell
        } else {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! LargeCustomCell

            return cell
        }
    }
```

Then define your SmallCustomCell and LargeCustomCell in separate classes for example:

```
class SmallCustomCell: UITableViewCell {
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        setup()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    fileprivate func setup() {
        // layout views + constraints
    }
}
```